# Editing TARGETDIR in orca so that it shows the application folder name appended after the TARGETDIR in UI of locatation of msi

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am creating a windows installer using Visual Studio 2010. I want to create another folder with my application name and then I want to copy components into that folder. Though the folder is created successfully I am facing some issue which seems to be severe. When a user tries to modify the path the default is also created but the location text in the GUI is not updated. i.e suppose a user changed the location to "D:\MyDesktop" then the GUI shows the location as "D:\MyDesktop" but I want to append my application name folder no matter wherever the application is installed. i.e "D:\MyDesktop\MYAPPNAME". Can it be done using orca? If yes, how?

Please note that my installer always creates the application name folder after the chosen location and installs the app in that folder. The only challenge is to append the application name folder in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had people ask me for this feature before but I resist.  The official standard for INSTALLDIR / TARGETDIR / INSTALLLOCATION (whatever you want to call it )  is  [ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product.   If a user says TARGETDIR=F:\   when so be it.  They get what they asked for.

If you still aren't happy, the easiest thing to do is set TERGETDIR = [ProgramFilesFolder]Company and then create a folder in the installer called Product and put everything under that.   As far as MSI / Add/Remove Programs is concerned  INSTALLDIR will be the parent folder.  So if they say TARGETDIR=F:\ it'll be F:\ but everything will in fact appear under F:\Product.

That said, I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do it in a straightforward way with Orca. With VS setups the default suggested folder name is supplied to the user (based on ProgramFiles Folder, Manufacture, Product name as Chris says) and if the user changes that folder then the files will be installed at that user specified location. What you are asking for is a custom action that runs off the button in the browse dialog that will append your name to the directory that was just chosen by the user, and works in the case that the user goes back and forwards several times without appending it multiple times! That's non-trivial if you know nothing about the internals of MSI files, and isn't what the user wants anyway.  If that's a common type of requirement in your setups, you should use another tool that lets you do this kind of thing. If you really don't want the user to change the default location you could always delete the Installation Folder dialog. Otherwise, I'm with Chris, let it go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Do you know about any tools which will help me to do this?

Comment: You need a tool that lets you run a custom action when the Next button is clicked, and that would append your name to the chosen path. That would be any of the full strength tools (WiX, InstallShield, Advanced installer) see list here http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm  but none of the "light" ones like IS LE or Visual Studio.